# Using XML-Typeprovider from another Module

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am doing an analysis on an XML File using F#.
Since the amount of code grew larger, i decided to split my code up into different files.

So i created a new File which looks something like this:

```
module Analyis

open FSharp.Data
open System

type someXml = XmlProvider<"someXMLFile.xml">

// Some Analysis functions down here
```

When i now try to use my type from another file, the subtypes that should be produced by the typeprovider cant be found anymore:

```
open Analysis

let importantFunction (data:someXml) =
    let thisDoesNotWork = data.someProperty

// more code
```

It only works if i load up the data inside of the function like this:

```
open Analysis

let importantFunction =
    let data = someXml.GetSample()

    let nowItWorks = data.someProperty

// more code
```

Questions:

- Is there a specific reason, why this does not work?
- How is there a "correct" way of separating an XmlType into another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the samples out into their own files.

I use it in the following way

```
module infoParser =

    open FSharp.Data

    type jsonProvider = JsonProvider<"./schemaSamples/fileSchema.json", EmbeddedResource="Parsers, fileschema.json">

    type Info (textJsonIn: string) =
        let parsedInfo = jsonProvider.Parse(textJsonIn)
```

Now you can create an Info "instance" and access the fields.

In my case I use the infoParser from a C# class and get the instance via a constructor call as

```
var info = new Info(myJsonString);
```

I based my code on an XML example so it *should* be OK for your needs.

Comment: If i use this approach twice - will there be a bigger memory footprint? Do you know, why my above code does not work?

Comment: I assume you were just missing the `.Parse` that I have in the last line of the code example. I guess the `GetSample` you used in your second try automatically does that step. Regarding the memory footprint, I don't think it will increase. Once the sample is parsed the result should be stored in parsedInfo and reused - but I haven't tested that.